# Hardware testing tool/suite

Tags: troubleshooting, installation

I just bought a new core i5 system (assembled) and started installing Windows 7. It was failing for many times and at some point got installed. After that, frequent crashes related to MEMORY. So checked the RAM using memtest86+ and found many errors.I got it replaced with the vendor and now if i install ANY OS, at some point in installation it either freezes completely with no response for hours, or restarts automatically. I tried installing Windows 7, Windows Vista and Ubuntu 9.10. 
I tested the new RAM again and found no problems in about 2 passes using memtest86+. I even updated the BIOS using bootable USB and even the problem persists. I am really not sure which hardware is causing trouble. I dont have any OS inside it, so i have to check using bootable CDs DVDs and USB only.

Please advice on how to proceed. Are there any suites/ separate tools for checking integrity of each hardware parts and troubleshoot it? I wanted to confirm which part is problematic before going for replacement.

Thanks a lot!

This is the config: `Core i5, MSI P55-GD65, GSKill 2x2GB, Seagate 500GB 7200rpm, CM Extreme 600W PSU, Saphhire Radeon 5770 1GB, LG DVD Writer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CM **Extreme** 600W PSU is not a good PSU for this system. Replace the PSU with a Corsair vx550 / CM **Real Power** 550W and try. If any of your friends have this PSU try replacing it with the ones mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sathya. Any way i can check it so that i can be sure other components are safe?

Comment: There are tools such as OCCT which can stress test and ensure that the components are safe, but before doing so you need to get the PSU replaced.

Comment: Welcome. do report back with your findings.

Comment: I do replaced PSU. But problem persisted after that. After doing some specific settings related to GSkill RAM in BIOS, It started running fine.